# 'If' statement In python turtle

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out is how to make an if statement

```
a.circle(b*(36-[(if p =3 (p*3), -i*36)
```

What I want is if the P value is three or greater it causes the circle to subtract p3 from 36 but if P is not equal to three or more then I want for the code to say I do not want it to subtract p from 36.

I'm using `python3.6` that I installed and run through terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating your request from English to code:

```
R = 36

# if the P value is three or greater 
if p >= 3:
    # it causes the circle to subtract p3 from 36 
    R -= p

# but if P is not equal to three or more 
else:
    # then I want for the code to say I do not want it to subtract p from 36.
    pass

a.circle(b * (R, -i * 36))   # attention, i is not defined
```

Comment: I didn't post the whole code only the problem child.  In the full code it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a Python 'traditional' if:

```
if condition:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

in one line:

```
value_if_condition_is_true if condition else value_if_condition_is_false
```

In your case you could try:

```
p*3 if p >=3 else -i*36
```

I hope this help you!